# Adding custom field in youtrack next to the comment tab

Tags: youtrack

Is it posible to add a custom field to youtrack next to the comment tab on the bottom?

We use youtrack 6.5 for now but if it is needed we can update to 7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible so far. There're are several predefined CF types in YouTrack. The CFs are displayed in a single column.